Problem with \today
In my code, when I use \today--command, the month-output is with lower-case letter, i. e., 27 aprile 2024. I'd like to have 27 Aprile 2024, with capital letter. Is there a way to obtain desired format?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\title{Today}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

Thank you in advanced
First Edit: I followed @Ulrike Fisher's suggestion, but I am sure that I failed. See the code below, and, please, correct mistakes (line 21). Thanks again
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\newif\ifOrdinalDayNumber \OrdinalDayNumberfalse
\def\OrdinalDayNumberOn{\OrdinalDayNumbertrue}
\def\OrdinalDayNumberOff{\OrdinalDayNumberfalse}
\def\dateitalian{%
\def\today{\ifnum\number\day=\@ne
\ifOrdinalDayNumber1\ap{o}\else1\fi
\else
\number\day
\fi~\ifcase\month\or
Gennaio\or Febbraio\or Marzo\or Aprile\or Maggio\or Giugno\or Luglio\or Agosto\or Settembre\or Ottobre\or Novembre\or Dicembre\fi\space \number\year}}%

\title{today}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Here the mistake (line 21)

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}



Sorry, but in Italian the names of the months have to be written lower case: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/alcuni-quesiti-sui-nomi-dei-mesi-e-dei-giorni-della-settimana/64#:~:text=I%20nomi%20dei%20giorni%20della,Domenica%20come%20nome%20proprio%20femminile).

I would still like them with a capital letter... .

In italiano sono minuscoli, scriverli maiuscoli è un inglesismo (e sbagliato, anche se molti lo fanno).

For my case, write 'Aprile' with capital letter is not wrong. Just checked.

I don't think it would do you any harm if I write the months with a capital letter. Isn't it?

look into italian.ldf, there is the command \dateitalian. Copy it into your document and redefine it (between \makeatletter/\makeatother.

I followed you suggestion and I edited my post but I still have an error. Why? Thx

@Puck See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/107497

Ulrike specified that the redefinition of \dateitalian should be sandwiched -- ok, that's a paraphrase, maybe "placed" is better -- between \makeatletter and \makeatother directives. You appear to have ignored this instruction.

Thx, you two solved my problem.

@Puck You're free to do what you like, I only warned you it's wrong :D


If you want to use datetime, it should be loaded after babel.

In this case, you don't want the ddmmyyyy option, that would print \today in the form “27/04/2024”.


How can you go against the Italian tradition that month names are not uppercased?
One way is to look into the support files of datetime and find the definition of \monthnameitalian; copy it in the document and modify the month names according to your (contrary to common usage) preference.
Or patch it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\monthnameitalian}{\c{or}}{\c{or}\c{MakeUppercase}}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Today}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}


Don't. Italian traditionally typesets month and day names lowercase (unless they start a sentence, of course).
With datetime2 you still need to change the month names.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMitalianmonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or Gennaio\or Febbraio\or Marzo\or Aprile\or Maggio\or Giugno\or
  Luglio\or Agosto\or Settembre\or Ottobre\or Novembre \or Dicembre\fi
}

\title{Today}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

